# Django ManytoMany Field Queryset for Exact and Similar Match

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class Disease(models.Model):
    name = CICharField("Disease Name", max_length=200, unique=True)
    symptoms = models.ManyToManyField(Symptom, through='DiseaseSymptom', related_name='diseases')


class Symptom(models.Model):
    name = CICharField("Symptom Name", max_length=200, unique=True)
```

On the front-end, I have multiple select boxes where users can select multiple Symptoms to find disease and that will pass to Disease model as symptoms_selected params.

I have the following get_queryset on Disease > views.py

```
def get_queryset(self):
        params = self.request.query_params
        query_symptoms = self.request.GET.getlist('symptoms_selected')
        if query_symptoms:
            i = 0
            queryset = Disease.objects.all()
            while i < (len(query_symptoms)):
                symptom = [query_symptoms[i]]
                queryset = queryset.filter(symptoms__id__in=symptom)
                i=i+1
        else:
            queryset = Disease.objects.all()
    return queryset
serializer_class = DiseaseSerializer
```

I am using Django REST API to pass the result data.

```
class DiseaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Disease
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'symptoms')
```

For eg: Disease Data:

**Disease A:**
Got Symptoms: A, B, C, D

**Disease B:**
Got Symptoms:  A, D, P, Q

**Disease C:**
Got Symptoms: A, Q, X, Y

Currently, if Users select 3 symptoms: A, D, Y. It returns Null. Instead of Null, I want to show users some similar matches with 2 and 1 symptoms.

**I want queryset will return:**

Exact match diseases i.e. 3 Symptoms matched diseases

2 Symptoms matched diseases

1 symptom matched diseases

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single `__in` filter will get all diseases that have at least one matching symptom

Then you can annotate the query with the count of matches and then order by this annotation to get the diseases with the most matches first

```
from django.db.models import Count

Disease.objects.filter(
    symptoms__id__in=query_symptoms
).annotate(
    matches=Count('symptoms')
).order_by('-matches')
```

The [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) tag can be used to group the results by number of matches in your template

```
{% regroup diseases by matches as diseases_grouped %}
<ul>
{% for match_count in diseases_grouped %}
    <li>{{ match_count.grouper }} matches
    <ul>
        {% for disease in match_count.list %}
          <li>{{ disease }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Use a [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to add a field to your serializer to access the annotation

```
class DiseaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    num_matches = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Disease
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'symptoms')

    def get_num_matches(self, obj):
        return getattr(obj, 'matches', None)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. If I select more symptoms, instead of narrowing down the result it will give more diseases.
Is there any way we can group the result by exact match, 2 matches, 1 match etc?

Comment: @ChandraShekharPandey yes, you can group the results in your template by using the `regroup` tag, added an example to the answer

Comment: @lain, Thank you so much for your time. I am not using the Django template. I need to send that data on Django REST API.

Comment: @ChandraShekharPandey how exactly do you want the response to look like? How is this API being consumed on the FE? Each result in the query will have a `matches` attribute with the number of matches which can be used to group on the FE

Comment: I have updated the question and added my serializer as well. Can you please tell me how can I pass matches on REST API response?

Comment: @ChandraShekharPandey Added an example of how to return the matches in your serializer

Comment: @lain, Can you please tell me how can I pass data of through table as well. Please see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70810754/django-pass-data-to-serializer-from-through-table-field

Comment: @lain, Can you check this one as well: