# Django Pass through Table field data to Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following models:

```
class Disease(models.Model):
    name = CICharField("Disease Name", max_length=200, unique=True)
    symptoms = models.ManyToManyField(Symptom, through='DiseaseSymptom', related_name='diseases')


class Symptom(models.Model):
    name = CICharField("Symptom Name", max_length=200, unique=True)

PRIORITY = (
    (0, 'Normal'),
    (1, 'Low'),
    (2, 'Medium'),
    (3, 'High'),
    (4, 'Key'),
)

class DiseaseSymptom(models.Model):
    disease = models.ForeignKey(Disease, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='disease_to_symptom')
    symptom = models.ForeignKey(Symptom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='symptom_to_disease')
    priority = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Priority', choices=PRIORITY, default=0)
```

On the front-end, I have multiple select boxes where users can select multiple Symptoms to find disease and that will pass to Disease model as symptoms_selected params.

I have the following get_queryset on Disease > views.py

```
def get_queryset(self):
        params = self.request.query_params
        query_symptoms = self.request.GET.getlist('symptoms_selected')
        if query_symptoms:
            queryset = Pattern.objects.filter(
                symptoms__id__in=query_symptoms
            ).annotate(
                matches=Count('symptoms')
            ).order_by('-matches')
        else:
            queryset = Disease.objects.all()
    return queryset
serializer_class = DiseaseSerializer
```

I am using Django REST API to pass the result data.

```
class DiseaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    symptoms_matches = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Disease
        fields = ('id', 'name','symptoms_matches')

    def get_symptoms_matches(self, obj):
        return getattr(obj, 'matches', None)
```

For eg: Disease Data:

**Disease A:**
Got Symptoms: A (priority=4), B (priority=2), C (priority=3), D (priority=2)

**Disease B:**
Got Symptoms:  A (priority=1), D (priority=2), P (priority=4), Q (priority=2)

If Users select 2 symptoms: A, D. I want queryset will return the count of key symptoms ( i.e. symptom with priority 4 ) matched on each Disease and the sum of the symptoms priority in each Disease.

For Eg. if Users select 2 symptoms: A, D. I want to achieve The serializer will return data like:

```
[
{
name: "Disease A"
key_symptoms_matched: 1
matched_symptoms_priority_sum: 6
}

{
name: "Disease B"
key_symptoms_matched: 0
matched_symptoms_priority_sum: 3
}

]
```

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to calculate the total sum of symptoms priorities in each disease

```
queryset = Disease.objects.filter(
                symptoms__id__in=query_symptoms
            ).annotate(
                matches=Count('symptoms')
            ).annotate(
                matched_symptoms_priority_sum =Sum('disease_to_symptom__priority')
            ).order_by('-matches','-matched_symptoms_priority_sum')
```

But I still need the number of key symptoms matched in each disease?